# Merge string item in list with another string

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to merge `String` item in list with another string ?
for example:
I have this list

```
final list1 = ['Hello'];
```

i need when click on button add `World` word to `Hello` word
so the list will be 
`['Hello World']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
final list1 = ['Hello']; // given

String hello = list1[0]; // get first letter
String world = 'World'; // letter you want to add

list1[0] = hello + ' ' + world; // concatenate both string and update list
```